# Custom JPanel with JButtons displays them one on top of another in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Basically, when i run the following code, instead of a panel containing three buttons next to each other i get a tiny panel that (i'm assuming) has all the buttons on top of each other. What's weird is that when i put all the code inside `Main()` it seems to work just fine, i can even add more buttons to `myTopLeftPanel` from main and they are displayed correctly, but when i split it into classes it starts acting weird. What's the cause of this? How can i fix it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    int height = 500;
    int width = (int)Math.round(height*1.61803);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }
    public Main() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MyTopLeftPanel myTopLeftPanel = new MyTopLeftPanel();
        JPanel top = addPanel(new BorderLayout());
        top.add(myTopLeftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setup();
    }
    void setup(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    JPanel addPanel(LayoutManager layout){
        JPanel temp = new JPanel();
        temp.setLayout(layout);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

```
class MyButtonPanel extends JPanel{
    JButton[] tab;
    public MyButtonPanel(int numOfButtons, LayoutManager layout) {
        this.tab = new JButton[numOfButtons];
        Arrays.fill(tab, new JButton());
        this.setLayout(layout);
    }
}
```

```
class MyTopLeftPanel extends MyButtonPanel{
    public MyTopLeftPanel(){
        super(3, new FlowLayout());
        tab[0].setBackground(Color.RED);
        tab[0].setText("R");
        tab[1].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        tab[1].setText("G");
        tab[2].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        tab[2].setText("B");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(tab[0], FlowLayout.LEFT);
        this.add(tab[1], FlowLayout.LEFT);
        this.add(tab[2], FlowLayout.LEFT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what that code is attempting to do. I see no reason to pass layout managers as a parameter or to have panels extend one another. It is an overly complicated design. Also, you should not be using "FlowLayout.LEFT" as a parameter to the add(...) method. A FlowLayout does not support any constraints. I suggest you just create a panel and add 3 buttons to it. The components should be created in the class where you actually add the components to the panel., not in the super class.

Comment: __do not__ extend concrete containers/components - they are designed for usage - so configures them as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Arrays.fill(tab, new JButton());`.

It creates only **one** instance of JButton which is assigned to each position of the array.

This should fix it:

```
class MyButtonPanel extends JPanel{
    JButton[] tab;
    public MyButtonPanel(int numOfButtons, LayoutManager layout) {
        this.tab = new JButton[numOfButtons];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++) {
            tab[i] = new JButton();
        }
        this.setLayout(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: funny thing is that i actually did it like this initially but then intellij was like "did you know you could do this with arrays.fill?" and i was like "okay :)"